# New Laravel Build - Timeout on post request

Tags: laravel

I have a new Laravel project and it has been a while since I had to start one from scratch. I have a simple post request to a controller with the route as below.

```php
Route::post('/JoinUs', 'UserController@functioName');
```

When the request is sent, I get a status code returned of 419 unknown status. There is a response that says "Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again." There is no delay in this message being returned.

This makes no sense to me. Is the controller not found? Is the function not found? It seems like there is a config problem somewhere.

Comment: Check any middleware, e.g. authentication, that is called before the controller and check the controller itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should Use `@csrf` in your form. Like this:

```php
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf <------
    ...
</form>
```

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf) section of the documentation.

Comment: I added a link to the documentation and also a sample of the code just to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you .